# how to encode pics paths in css based on base64?

Tags: css, encoding, assets

I've recently encountered with sites that their site's assets (logo, resource pics) are like below:

```
background: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhbAAbAMQAADRNU////8PAvwCq3KunpYeCf+fm5RSGp3BpZgDW7tvZ2WRdWaCbmVhQTRSltPPy8re0sszMzHt1cgDs9xTBwJOOjBCNsgC/5TRZWBDOzd7e1vf39xCduYiCgEA3MwAAACH5BAEHAB4ALAAAAABsABsAAAX/oCeKDaEEaGBA0ui+cCzPdG3fM5HuqYHgQBtvNAzCeClZ44REdozQV9EzjVKbMl2zubBGp9UvFtZAKgiQCBLihYJ37SsyxuD9RgheJB58J9tbMWopbC55O3t8gHCKYSKDKAwvDQ87kopejlaakCoNLwsGKASYi398mlo9LUANDBGVKixHcx4VTAoMn3IoRFsBChW7SgSivzELTQbCNqpIBqwiTUtr0oy8Ww9PMc7HMQK  /AndkTL8B29go5UV+5gGXLhDup5PrSBHjI90BEcY7u  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") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

How is this possible? and how we can do such encoding in our site?

**EDIT**
Am not really good at this point, if it's possible please help a little more to get the answer, I encoded my picture an got the code which is too long about 2 pages now I've added that in css but gain no success!! (by the way does that help in improving performance?)

Comment: It's base64 encoding. It's not encryption.

Comment: and how we can do that for ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, it's not encryption but encoding; basically it's the same resource you'd normally refer to externally embedded into the css. You can try making one yourself or using [one of the numerous tools available online](http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker); [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) is surprisingly thorough as well.

While it does not offer any content protection (i.e. anyone can still save the file), when used correctly it does offer some benefits. Main one is less http requests - rather than requesting every individual image resource, they are already all downloaded! Just don't dump *all* your site's graphics into the css file and stick with the elements that are used on almost every page instead.

IMO, another great benefit is easier resource management. Instead of spriting small icons you are effectively operating on individual graphic files (no background bleeding artifacts etc.) - but you're not being punished for it with significant file size overhead (suggested to be as low as 3% with gzip enabled).

Basically all browsers but IE7 support the method to a degree. There are some further limitations as to content type/size (e.g. max 32kb for IE8)

Answer (score -1):

The source of image is just encoded using BASE-64. It is faster. If you want to decode this use e.g. http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp and choose export to `.bin` file. Than save, change extension to .gif and voila. :)

As I wrote it is faster, but less convenient in my opinion.

Comment: what? why would you need to change extension to .gif? base64-encoded data is embeddable inline in the context above

Comment: I know, but if you just copy that the image will be corrupted (there are characters which you cannot copy like NULL). So you need to export entire file - with these characters.

but wait.. what are you talking about? :D

Comment: The claim that it is faster, I assume is based on the fact that there are less http requests... but does anyone know if base64 images are cached by the browser? If not, that would be a very serious performance issue.

Comment: @sethcall: base64 images are not separate resources. You're using them either in a css file that probably gets cached (good) or inline in html that probably shouldn't be cached (bad, unless it's a throwaway image like a captcha)

Comment: @Kobra: what null characters? the whole point of base64 is to represent binary data in an ASCII string format i.e. without characters like NULL

Comment: @o.v. yes but the browser probably decodes the image everytime from the cached css.  That still sounds fast but I wouldn't assume it so, at least, relative to a normally cached image.

Comment: @o.v. oh.. you mean encoded string - yes you're right, but I mean decoded string :)